# doing a loop inside a loop using mysql ressources

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to do some loops in loop using mysql but it seems that there not interpreted

it returns only the first result then nothing even If I have many records in my database, It should return everything

below is my code that display the results

```
while ($cr = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)):
    $i = 0;
    ++$i;
    ?>
    <div style="width:200px"  class="fif"><table style="width:100%">
        <tr class="fbgreybox">
        <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center;font-weight: bold">
            <img src="images/calendar_2.png"> Séance du : <?php echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($cr['record'])); ?>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT `exercise` FROM `workouts` WHERE `record` = '{$cr['record']}' AND `user`= {$_SESSION['userid']} GROUP BY `exercise`";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        while ($exo = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) :
        ?>
            <tr class="fbinfobox">
            <td colspan="3" style="text-align: left">
                <img src="images/Sport-dumbbell.png"> ////<?php echo exerciseName($exo['exercise']); ?>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;font-weight: bold">Séries</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;font-weight: bold">Reps</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;font-weight: bold">Poids</td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        $rqt = "SELECT `set_number`, `reps`, `weight` FROM `workouts` WHERE `exercise` = {$exo['exercise']} AND `record` = '{$cr['record']}' AND `user` = {$_SESSION['userid']} ORDER BY `set_number`";
        $result2 = mysql_query($rqt);
        while ($detail = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)):
            ?>
            <tr>
            <td>
                Série ////<?php echo $detail['set_number']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $detail['reps']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $detail['weight']; ?>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        endwhile;
        endwhile;
        ?>
    </table>
    </div>
    <?php
endwhile;
```

there is not mistakes in the code so I really do not understand why it is not interpreted.

anykind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You should use MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements. mysql_ functions have been deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using $result in both  mysql_fetch_assoc() function. AVOID THAT.

In inner loop you can use another variable:

```
$sql = "SELECT `exercise` FROM `workouts` WHERE `record` = '{$cr['record']}' AND `user`= {$_SESSION['userid']} GROUP BY `exercise`";
$workoutsResult = mysql_query($sql);
while ($exo = mysql_fetch_assoc($workoutsResult )) :
```

Comment: Where are escapes, where is mysqli_* ?

Comment: I dont not know what is mysqli_* And escapes are on the header that is not displayed there

Comment: @StanislasPiotrowski: mysql_* are depricated from PHP 5.3 and instead you can use mysqli or PDO statements

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would first loop through the first query and put it in an array.
Then you loop through this array, and search for the inner queries and also put in arrays inside the other array.

Then, you loop through them to build your table.

It'll make your code cleaner, and will avoid problems like the one you're having, the one @Suresh pointed out.